# Getting an undefined value when trying to load Mocha through RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js, testcase

I started to write test-cases, for this process I used `require.js` to load `mocha.js and chai.js` files. For this I written the following code.

```
require(["tests/lib/mocha","tests/lib/chai"],function(mocha,chai){
  //loading all the test case files
  console.log(mocha);
  console.log(chai);
});
```

`chai` was working fine, but `mocha` getting `undefined`.I don't know what's the problem can anyone help me.

Comment: Is this code running in a browser? (RequireJS can be used in Node too so it is not obvious.) Also, please add your RequireJS config to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & using a shim exports solved it.

```
require.config({
paths: {
    mocha: 'bower_components/mocha/mocha'
},
shim: {
    mocha: { exports: 'mocha' }
}
});
```

It's a been odd, because chai don't need this to work :-|.

Answer (score -1):

Did you run it under Chrome? This seems to be a Chrome issue.
I ran into the same issue and switching to Firefox solved it. Also IE11 worked.
And Chrome Canary did also work, if you want to stay in the Chrome world.